# Warning: unchecked method invocation: method fillReport in class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager

Tags: java, oracle-adf

I'm using oracle j deveolper 12c and jasper report 5.6.0 to do my report ,the report is works in local (integrated weblogic) and there are no errors but there are many Warning:

**Warning: unchecked method invocation: method fillReport in class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager is applied to given types
required: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport,java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object>,java.sql.Connection
found: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport,java.util.Map,java.sql.Connection.**

when i run my application"report" in glassfish4.1 server i get these error also from log server :

**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser**
This is my report:

```
public void runReport(String repPath, java.util.Map param) throws Exception {
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
    HttpServletResponse response = getResponse();
    ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    ServletContext context = getContext();
    InputStream fs = context.getResourceAsStream("/Reports/" + repPath);//foldername
    JasperReport template = (JasperReport)JRLoader.loadObject(fs);
    template.setWhenNoDataType(WhenNoDataTypeEnum.NO_DATA_SECTION);
    conn = getConnection();
    JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(template, param, conn);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(print, baos);
    out.write(baos.toByteArray());
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
    } catch (Exception jex) {
    jex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
    close(conn);
    }
    }
    
    public Connection getDataSourceConnection(String dataSourceName) throws Exception {
    
    Context ctx = new InitialContext();
    DataSource ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup(dataSourceName);
    
    return ds.getConnection();
    
    }

    private Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
    //System.out.println(con);
    return getDataSourceConnection("jdbc/SSMODS");
    
    }

    public ServletContext getContext() {
    return (ServletContext)getFacesContext().getExternalContext().getContext();
    }

    public HttpServletResponse getResponse() {
    return (HttpServletResponse)getFacesContext().getExternalContext().getResponse();
    }

    public static FacesContext getFacesContext() {
    return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    }

    public BindingContainer getBindings() {
    return BindingContext.getCurrent().getCurrentBindingsEntry();
    }

    public void close(Connection con) {
    if (con != null) {
    try {
     con.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    

    }
```

Comment: This is caused when there is a class file that your code depends on and it is present at compile time but not found at runtime. Look for differences in your build time and runtime classpaths.

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko how can i know about this class!